# Line-break problem with print text function

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I have issue with my code. It's a function who take some parameters and display text on my window.
But, if I have '\n' in my string, I gonna have a weird symbol and not my line-break.

This is my code :

```
void displayText(int posx, int posy, std::string text)
{
    SDL_Surface* surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(_font, text.c_str(), _white);
    SDL_Texture* Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage);
    SDL_Rect Message_rect;
    SDL_GetClipRect(surfaceMessage, &Message_rect);
    Message_rect.x = posx;
    Message_rect.y = posy;
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Message, NULL, &Message_rect);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surfaceMessage);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(Message);
}
```

And the output with `std::string a = "This\nis\na\ntext\n"`

[image]

PS : The print of renderer is not in this function and it's normal.

Comment: Something wrong with the [`TTF_Render*_Wrapped()`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_ttf/blob/main/SDL_ttf.h#L219-L232) family of functions?

Comment: I don't know, all work except \n and it's ascii character

Answer (score 0):

use `TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped`. It takes additional parameter: width in pixels after which the text will break into next line.
`\n` also works with the *_Wrapped functions